# mod_rewrite to a specific page content

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect all pages other than `index.php` to a specific section inside the pages.

Like this: `example.com?pagerequest` to `example.com?pagerequest#navigation`

Comment: What web server are you using?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am using Apache, I have a big logo my page, and I want to scroll the pages to the navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
RewriteCond    %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.html
RewriteRule    ^(.*)$         $1?%{QUERY_STRING}#navigation [R,NE]
```

Comment: Thank you Krist, I think it is almost there, but did not work yet.

Comment: The [NE] flag is important. Without it the # gets escaped.
Also add rewrite logging to your config, to see what is really going on.

Comment: It is writing the entire path several times like /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs 
and at the end it adds ?${QUERY_STRING}#navigation.
So I am took of the ${QUERY_STRING} and it corretly adds only #navigation to the end.
Now I am trying to change the pattern ^(.*)$

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. Should be &{QUERY_STRING}